# Need Help - Code Changes For Drop Down Options Form - Change Submission to URL link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an existing drop down menu button.  See at http://testing.siteapp.mobi/test

Right now, When user clicks on blue drop down menu button, a blank fied opens, which the user clicks on and then a drop down appears with 4 states listed.  The user then selects 1 of the states. Once selected, the state selected populates the blank field, then the user clicks the existing "GO" button.

This is code from a submition form.  So I need to change it. I need this to do one of the following, which ever is easier:

1) When user clicks on blue drop down menu button, a blank fied opens, which the user clicks on and then a drop down appears with 4 states listed.  The user then selects 1 of the states. Once selected, the state selected populates the blank field, then the user clicks the existing "GO" button. I need this to take the user directly to a designated URL. Each of the 4 states will have a different URL. So depending on the one selected, they will end up at a different URL.

OR

2) In stead of the selected state populating into the blank field and the user clicking the "GO" button........As soon as the user selects the state from the existing drop down menu, the user is taken directly to a designated URL. The same as above, but no "GO" button.

You can see what I have now at http://testing.siteapp.mobi/test then right click, then View Page Source.

I appreciate any help.  Keep in mind I am a novice, so if you decide to help me, you will have to be as explicit as possible and probaly actually show me the correct code and where to insert any changes need to my existing code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>

   <title>Test</title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
   <meta name="keywords" content="" />
   <meta name="description" content="" />

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://files.mobilebuilder.net/Styles/mobile-frontend/css/styles.css?v=1.0.0.75" type="text/css" media="all" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://files.mobilebuilder.net/Styles/mobile-frontend/css/styles-ltr.css?v=1.0.0.75" type="text/css" media="all" />
   <!--[if IE 7]><link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://files.mobilebuilder.net/Styles/mobile-frontend/css/ie7Fix.css?v=1.0.0.75"/><![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 8]><link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://files.mobilebuilder.net/Styles/mobile-frontend/css/ie8Fix.css?v=1.0.0.75"/><![endif]-->
   <noscript><link href="http://files.mobilebuilder.net/Styles/mobile-frontend/css/styles-no-script.css?v=1.0.0.75" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /></noscript>

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var gResources = 'http://files.mobilebuilder.net/'; 


       var gP = '156908';
       l10n = { };
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.mobilebuilder.net/Scripts/jquery-1.10.0.min.js?v=1.0.0.75"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/Handlers/l10n/app.l10n.js.ashx?lang=en-US&v=1.0.0.75"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.mobilebuilder.net/Styles/mobile-frontend/js/app.main.min.js?v=1.0.0.75"></script>




<style type="text/css">

body { background-color:#ffffff;background-image:none; }
.content-mobile  {   }

body, a.base-link {color:#313131;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;}

a { color:#313131;}




.content-mobile .block-head.header { background-color:#373737;background-color:rgba(55,55,55,0);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(55,55,55,1) 0%,rgba(41,41,41,1) 100%);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(55,55,55,1) 0%,rgba(41,41,41,1) 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(55,55,55,1) 0%,rgba(41,41,41,1) 100%);background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,color-stop(0%, rgba(55,55,55,1)),color-stop(100%, rgba(41,41,41,1)));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(55,55,55,1) 0%,rgba(41,41,41,1) 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(top,rgba(55,55,55,1) 0%,rgba(41,41,41,1) 100%);-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#373737',endColorstr='#292929')"; }
.content-mobile .block-head.alink, .shopping-cart-notification { background-color:#373737;background-color:rgba(55,55,55,0);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(55,55,55,1) 0%,rgba(41,41,41,1) 100%);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(55,55,55,1) 0%,rgba(41,41,41,1) 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(55,55,55,1) 0%,rgba(41,41,41,1) 100%);background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,color-stop(0%, rgba(55,55,55,1)),color-stop(100%, rgba(41,41,41,1)));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(55,55,55,1) 0%,rgba(41,41,41,1) 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(top,rgba(55,55,55,1) 0%,rgba(41,41,41,1) 100%);-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#373737',endColorstr='#292929')"; }
.content-mobile .block-head.alink .header-link { }

.content-mobile .block .block-head.header h2 {color:#ffffff;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:18px;}
.content-mobile .block .block-head.alink .link, .shopping-cart-notification {color:#ffffff;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:18px;}

.content-mobile p, .content-mobile .block-feed p,   .content-mobile .form label,.content-mobile .gallery h4,
.content-mobile .description, .content-mobile .form table th, .content-mobile .form table td,
.content-mobile .back-link, .content-mobile .home-link,    .content-mobile .geo-locations p   {color:#313131;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;}

.content-mobile .block .block-head.alink .link,  .content-mobile .block .block-head.header h2 { text-align:center; } 


.gallery .gallery-navigation li { background:#ffffff; }

 .content-mobile .main-footer a { color:#313131;}



   .content-mobile .button-holder a, .content-mobile .button-holder-image a { color: #FFFFFF; }

   .content-mobile .button-holder { padding:0;margin:15px 0; }
   .content-mobile .button-holder a { margin:0 auto;padding:10px 14px;width:250px;height:25px;outline:none;border:0 none;background:transparent url(http://storage.mobilebuilder.net/common/images/library_buttons_06.png) left top no-repeat; }
   .content-mobile .button-holder a .button-text { position:static;display:block;margin:0;padding:0;border:0 none;font-size:18px;background:transparent; }
   .content-mobile .button-holder a .lt, .content-mobile .button-holder a .rt,
   .content-mobile .button-holder a .lb, .content-mobile .button-holder a .rb { display:none; }
   .coupon-snippet .coupon-border { border-color:#313131; }







</style>



</head>
    <body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 100);" is_preview="False" mode="page" storage_start_url="http://storage.mobilebuilder.net/" relative_start_url="/">
        <div class="content-mobile">
            <div><div id="root">


    <div class="block clearfix collapsible-container">



<div class="block-head header collapsible-trigger"  style="margin:20px;-moz-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;-o-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;-webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;background-color:#0e6db0;background-image:none;" > 
            <div class="wrapper">

                <h2  style="padding-left:40px;">Begin Here</h2>
                    <span class="header-glyph">
                            <em></em>
                    </span>
            </div>  
 </div>
                <div class='block-content clearfix collapsible-content' style="background-color:#f5f5f5;background-image:none;">               

<div id="contactform0" class="form">
    <div>
        <form id="form0" method="post" action="">
            <input name="id" type="hidden" value="156908"/>
            <input name="lang" type="hidden" value="en-US"/>
            <input name="number" type="hidden" value="0"/>
            <div class="form-fields">

        <label class="field-selectbox-label">






            <span class="form-field-name">Choose Service Location

                    <span title="Choose Service Location is required." id="span_Choose Service Location">*</span>

            </span>



                <select title="Choose Service Location" class="field-select selectbox valid" name="Choose Service Location">
                    <option></option>
                            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                            <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                </select>

        </label>

            </div>
             <div style="display: none;"><input type="text" name="PrevSp" id="PrevSp"/></div>
            <div class="ta-center">
                    <input id="submit_form" onclick="return checkForm(0)" class="submit_form" type="submit" value="GO"  />
            </div>


        </form>
    </div>
</div>

                </div>          
    </div>


<div class="main-footer">
            <div>
            <!-- See Full Website -->
        </div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
       var pa = document.createElement("img");
       var referrerHost = "";
       if (document.referrer) {
          var tempA = document.createElement('a');
          tempA.href = document.referrer;
          referrerHost = tempA.hostname;
       }
       var src = "http://" + document.location.host + "/handlers/visitstatistic.ashx";
       var innerPart = "path=" + document.location.pathname + "&referrer=" + referrerHost + "&r=" + (new Date()).getTime();
       if (document.location.search) {
           src += document.location.search;
           src += "&" + innerPart;
       }
       else {
           src += "?" + innerPart;
       }
       pa.width = 1;
       pa.height = 1;
       pa.onload = function () {
          document.body.removeChild(pa);
       };
       pa.src = src;
       document.body.appendChild(pa);
    })();
</script>

            </div></div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery, try this:

```
<select id = "stateSelect" title="Choose Service Location" class="field-select selectbox valid" name="Choose Service Location">
                    <option></option>
                            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                            <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                </select>
<script>
$('#stateSelect').change(function() {
var s = $('#stateSelect').val();
location.href = '/' + s + '';
});
</script>
```

This assumes the target URL is on the same domain with the option value as the last part of the URL.  If it's different, you can just add the full path in the last part of the jquery function.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Cra28/)

If you need a different URL (domain) for each state, you could add the URL as the value of each option and make an absolute path at `location.href':

```
<select id = "stateSelect" title="Choose Service Location" class="field-select selectbox valid" name="Choose Service Location">
                    <option></option>
                            <option value="alabama.com">Alabama</option>
                            <option value="florida.com">Florida</option>
                            <option value="georgia.com">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="louisiana.com">Louisiana</option>
                </select>
<script>
$('#stateSelect').change(function() {
var s = $('#stateSelect').val();
location.href = 'http://www.' + s + '';
});
</script>
```

[Second Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3sbx/)

Comment: This doesn't account for different URL's for different states but if you assign a `data` attribute with the proper URL to each `<option>` element then you can pass that into your `location.href` and you will have an even more solid function and one that is much less expensive than mine.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I had assumed that the page for each state was on the same domain (whether the same as the select element or another one).  You could of course make the value of each option the target URL and then just change the last line of my code to something like `location.href = 'http://www.' + s + '';` Revised [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3sbx/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so sideroxylon's function is far more lean than mine but it actually doesn't account for different URL's for different states. I did come up with an all inclusive answer for what your are looking for using the "GO" button and my code includes the following functionality:

1. Drop the form down when the user clicks the "begin" bar.
2. Register the value when the user changes it and pass it to the go buttton.
3. Alert the user if they click "GO" without choosing anything.
4. Open a new tab/window when the user clicks "GO" then reset the form element. (Note: Instead of opening a new window you can cause the current window to change by replacing all instances of `_blank` with `_self`.

**NOTE**: Mine also requires that you use **JQuery** so first you need to insert this code in the `<head>` section of your document:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, to make it function like your example link, you use the follow JQuery:

```
// Drop the form down when user clicks the "begin" bar
$(".block-head").on("click", function(){
    $(".block-content").slideToggle();
});

// Set two global variables
var state = $("select.field-select").val();
var x = document.getElementById("form0");

// Register the selection each time the user changes it and pass it to the "GO" button
$(".field-select").change(function(){
    var state = $("select.field-select").val();
    $("#go").on("click", function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (state === "") {
            $("#choose").text(" *Please choose a state -->");
        } else if(state === "Alabama"){
            window.open("YOUR URL HERE", "_blank");
            x.reset();
            state = "";
            $("#choose").text("");
        } else if (state === "Florida"){
            window.open("YOUR URL HERE", "_blank");
            x.reset();
            state = "";
            $("#choose").text("");
        } else if (state === "Georgia"){
            window.open("YOUR URL HERE", "_blank");
            x.reset();
            state = "";
            $("#choose").text("");
        } else if (state === "Louisiana"){
            window.open("YOUR URL HERE", "_blank");
            x.reset();
            state = "";
            $("#choose").text("");
        }
        console.log(state); // This line is for testing purposes 
     });
});

// Account for when the user clicks "GO" right off the bat without choosing anything
$("#go").on("click", function(){
if(state === "") {$("#choose").text(" *Please choose a state -->");}    
});
```

Just replace the javascript code you currently have in your HTML `<body>` with the code I provided and you are good to go!

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/N7wN6/1/)

Comment: NOTE: I cleaned up your HTML & CSS a little for my demo but there is still a lot of extraneous divs.  You'll have to take care of those and update your CSS to style and position elements how you want them. Good luck!